# How to fetch name of all files in google drive using google drive api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to fetch name of all the files in my google drive but the problem is that I can fetch only specific amount of file how can I remove this limitation and fetch all files
here's the code provided by google on their [site](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)

I am using google drive api v3

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this code there is a variable pageSize whose value is 10 and if I increase its value so I can fetch more files but I want to fetch all files so how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) has an optional paramter called pagesize

> pageSize   integer The maximum number of files to return per page. Partial or empty result pages are possible even before the end of the files list has been reached. Acceptable values are 1 to 1000, inclusive. (Default: 100)

You have set yours to pageSize=10 you should set it up to 1000 and then use the nextPageToken to select the next set of rows if there are more.

I am not a python developer the following code is a guess.

```
page_token = saved_start_page_token;
while page_token is not None:
    response = service.changes().list(pageToken=page_token,
    pageSize=1000, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')
```